# How do I scaffold a new C++ project using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

Is there a way to quickly scaffold a basic C++ CMake project using CMake itself? For examples in an empty directory calling `cmake new` then CMake asks a few questions e.g. project name, lisence and generator. Then CMake generates all the required files and directories, e.g. CMakeLists.txt file, src directory and probably initialize it as Git repository.

Comment: You can write a [yeoman](https://yeoman.io/) generator. It's not CMake but you can generate CMake projects. I did it for my projects and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such features and I don't see a point to add scaffolding into CMake itself. There are free and popular tools specifically for scaffolding purpose, so I suggest you to go to [yeoman](https://yeoman.io/generators/) or [slush](http://slushjs.github.io/generators/#/) generators search pages and search for **cmake**.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a CMake function to create an empty project with a specific layout.
[file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) command helps you to create files and directories.